# Use Picard's method to find two decimal places the smallest positive solution to the equation $\sin x=x\cos x$

Tags: real-analysis

A question from *Introduction to Analysis* from Arthur Mattuck:

> Use Picard's method to find two decimal places the smallest positive solution to the equation $\sin x=x\cos x$.
>
> How many iterations would be required to get the answer to within $10^{-n}$, and why?

I get the recursive equation $$x_{n+1}=\arctan x_n+\pi, x_0=1.$$
Then, $$x_1 \approx 3.926990,\\x_2 \approx 4.463040, \\x_3 \approx 4.491966,\\x_4 \approx 4.493341,\\ x_5 \approx 4.493406, \\x_6 \approx 4.493409.$$
It seems one need $n$ iterations to get the answer to within $10^{-n}$, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

After rewriting the equation as $x=\arctan x$ we see that there is a unique positive solution $\xi>1$. Starting with $x_0=1$, the sequence of iterates is increasing and converges to $\xi$. The rate of convergence is determined by the size of the derivative of he right hand side of the equation, which in this case in $1/(1+x^2)$. Its maximum on $[1,\xi]$ is $1/2$, so that each iteration reduces the error by $1/2$. This is not too good. But  $x_n>3$ for $n>0$, and the maximum of $1/(1+x^2)$ on $[3,\xi]$ is $1/10$. In fact, we have a better estimate, since $x_2>4$ and the maximum of $1/(1+x^2)$ on $[4,\xi]$ is $1/17$. That is, after the second iteration, the error is divided by $17$ on each new iteration.